# Linkbutton Eventhandler dont working in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a linkbutton in gridview and i want to click event on code behind but it doesnt working.

When i click linkbutton postback is working but it doesnt reach codes inside "txt_SARTLI_FORMAT_Click".(sorry about my eng)

// My Grid

```
<cc1:xGrid ID="XGrid_Kolonlar" runat="server" 
      Width="100%"
      ...
      OnRowDataBound="XGrid_Kolonlar_RowDataBound">
```

// CS

```
    protected void XGrid_Kolonlar_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ...
            ...
            txt_SARTLI_FORMAT.ID = "btn_SartliFormat";
            txt_SARTLI_FORMAT.Text = SARTLI_FORMAT != "" ? "Göster" : "Yeni";
            txt_SARTLI_FORMAT.CommandArgument = SARTLI_FORMAT;
            txt_SARTLI_FORMAT.Click += new EventHandler(txt_SARTLI_FORMAT_Click);
       }
   }


    void txt_SARTLI_FORMAT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... (this codes dont work)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event `ItemCommand` which you'll have to use. 
Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcommand.aspx).
Edit: It's not rowitemcommand, it is ItemCommand.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to write the code in **OnRowCommand** event because when you have any control inside the grid and you have to work on its event then you must have write and event called **OnRowCommand** and from that event you can reach your any code in it.